# Como faço comandos genéricos em shellscript para um script de instalação de programas?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script, automatização

Como faço para fazer com que os comandos aceitem todas as possibilidades no código? (Genérico)

Estou tentando fazer um script de automação para instalar todos os programas que utilizo regularmente no ubuntu 20.04.

Neste caso tento adicionar uma chave de repositório utilizando wget mas não funciona!

```
keys_repository=( "https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc" )

echo "Downloading repository keys..." && sleep 1 
for key in ${keys_repository[@]}; do
  wget -q  $key -O- | apt-key add -
done
```

Neste outro caso tento adicionar os repositórios mas também não funciona, pois não sei como fazer o comando mais genérico possível!

```
arch_repositories=( "[arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main"
                    "[arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" )

echo "Adding repositories deb..." && sleep 1 
for repository in ${repositories[@]}; do
  apt-add-repository "deb "$repository -y
done
```

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Veja um exemplo de instalador e perceba a cadeia de ifs: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/blob/main/bin/rbenv-installer